Update one of the key value in the ARRAY Column in Snowflake
Requirement : To update the Array Column for all those which is having one of the key value as empty
details_array in table looks like below
DETAILS_ARRAY
[
  {
    "dl_country": "",
    "typeid": "U"
  }
]

Tried as below statement to update the key value but in vain
MERGE INTO tgt
USING (
  SELECT a_id, d_id, dl_country
  FROM doc_fix
  WHERE a_id = 12321 AND d_id = 88899
) src 
ON tgt.a_id = src.a_id AND tgt.d_id = src.d_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
  DETAILS_ARRAY = OBJECT_INSERT(tgt.DETAILS_ARRAY,'dl_country', src.dl_country)
;

Error:
Invalid argument types for function 'OBJECT_INSERT': (ARRAY, VARCHAR(21), VARCHAR(16777216), BOOLEAN)

Above is the example for one id , but i need to update all id's having empty string in the dl_country field

try to update the array column for all rows where the key value dl_country is empty:
UPDATE tgt
SET DETAILS_ARRAY = NEW_DETAILS_ARRAY
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a_id,
    d_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(
      CASE 
        WHEN json_data.value:dl_country::string = '' THEN OBJECT_INSERT(json_data.value, 'dl_country', src.dl_country)
        ELSE json_data.value
      END
    ) AS NEW_DETAILS_ARRAY
  FROM tgt,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => DETAILS_ARRAY) json_data,
  (
    SELECT a_id, d_id, dl_country
    FROM doc_fix
    WHERE dl_country = ''
  ) src
  WHERE tgt.a_id = src.a_id
  AND tgt.d_id = src.d_id
  GROUP BY a_id, d_id
) AS subquery
WHERE tgt.a_id = subquery.a_id
AND tgt.d_id = subquery.d_id;

